# Angularjs: though ng-click triggers, the toggleMenu() controller method is not fired

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Here is the snippet. When I tap the td, the ng-click-active is set (as shown below), but the $parent.toggleMenu() is not fired:

```
<td class="bigmacButton toggleMenu ng-click-active" ng-click="$parent.toggleMenu()">
    <div></div>
</td>
```

I originally had ng-click="toggleMenu()" but I suspected a scope issue. I even tried $parent.$parent.toggleMenu() without success.

I'm stuck with this. What would you try to diagnostic the issue and then fix? I really need an investigation method here.

[EDIT 1]

I forgot to mention that this works well on Safari/Mac, but the issues is present on iPad/iOS.

[EDIT 2]

Within the same code environment (the App), I duplicated the tag to put it elsewhere in the DOM and it works. This should me a proof it's a scope issue, isn't?

[EDIT 3]

My investigation led me to the point where I found what triggers the issue. The td code is followed by another one which a ng-class as follows. When I removed the ng-cass, the toggleMenu() works!
From this, I tried to set the 'on' or 'off' class manually in the inspector and this makes the issue reappearing! Don't get it.

```
                    <td 
                        class="bigmacButton toggleMenu" ng-click="toggleMenu()"
                        style="vertical-align: top; padding-top: 10px">
                        <div></div>
                    </td>

                    <td 
                        nng-class="{'on':config.keynote, 'off':!config.keynote}"
                        class="keynoteButton"
                        style="vertical-align: top;"
                        ng-hide="getPage()=='/settings'"
                        ng-click="config.keynote=!config.keynote">
                        <div style="-webkit-filter: invert(100%); -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);"></div>
                    </td>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using `ng-touch` as a dependency in your application? And if you are, is the element with the `ng-click` directive wrapped in an element with another `ng-click` directive somewhere?

Comment: I do use ng-click. But alas, no ng-click embedding.

Answer (score 0):

To investigate the issue using the Chrome browser, I would recommend the use of Batarang (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en). It is a Chrome extension that lets you inspect the angular scopes and lets you debug your application =)

Related to your problem, if you provide more info or a fiddle of the problem, we may try to help you more, might be as simple as a mistaken Controller for that area of HTML or as complex as scope issues, so provide for info if you want more accurate help =)

Good luck!

Comment: I would love to provide you with a fiddle, but unfortunately, I cannot manage to reproduce it. The code works nice on my mac (Safari or chrome). But not on the iPad.